# Jquery Fancybox 2 adds a margin-right?

Tags: jquery, margins, fancybox-2

When I use the Fancybox 2 jquery plugin, a margin-right of 23px gets added (width of scrollbar).

Here's the website (click on the Site Map button):
http://kevinlouisdesign.com/projects/Canu/web/

What I don't like is that it makes the content jump to the left when the fancybox shows up. I'd like to get rid of this margin-right style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a `CSS` fix. On the `.fancybox-lock` style, get rid of the `overflow-y: scroll`, so the style that looks like this:

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Should instead look like this:

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This will handle it for you.