# Fancybox pushes background by adding a margin-right

Tags: jquery, fancybox, margin

My test site: rockitmembers.us

Site is Wordpress.org, not using a plugin.

**Code inside header.php is:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rockitmembers.us/wp-content/themes/acosmin-v3/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

**This code in footer.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rockitmembers.us/wp-content/themes/acosmin-v3/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe").fancybox({
       fitToView : false,
       autoSize : false,
       scrolling : 'no',
    maxWidth        : 820,
    maxHeight       : 600,
    width           : 800,
    height          : 600,
    type            : 'iframe'
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**And this code in my wordpress post for the BUY A LICENSE button:**

```
<a href="http://www.rockitmembers.us/fancyboxtest.html" class="iframe rollover"><span class="displace">Buy A Beat</span></a>
```

Click the BUY A LICENSE button on the first post (My Reflection). Fancybox functions fine except it adds a 17px margin-right to fancybox-lock which messes up the look of the background, I think it's pushing the scroll bar out? I'm not sure. When you inspect it in Chrome it adds `<body class="fancybox-lock" style="margin-right: 17px;">` when the buy a license button is clicked.

I tried the suggestion in this post [Jquery Fancybox 2 adds a margin-right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902531/jquery-fancybox-2-adds-a-margin-right) by editing jquery.fancybox.css and taking out `overflow-y: scroll;` but that still didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML and script please in the post as once the site you linked is down, changed or gone this question is of no use to any user in the future who might experience similar issue.

Comment: There's also the whole "why would I go visit some random site?" issue. I shouldn't have to go "view source" to help you...

Comment: @FrançoisWahl sorry, I added the code, if any other code is needed let me know.

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is caused by the `<iframe>` not having a width specified, but it's been a while since I last used Fancybox. Let me see if I can verify that...

Comment: remove any padding or margin from the `body` tag .... add those settings to a wrapper container instead. Most importantly don't override the margins of `.fancybox-lock` selector as suggested. The issue is generated by your own css `body` settings but once your remove margin from body everything should work fine. Check a similar scenario http://stackoverflow.com/a/14388439/1055987

Comment: @JFK I fixed the issue by changing my site's background image and setting the background color of the middle containers `#container` and `#header` to black. Didn't have to delete the extra margin fancybox-lock adds. Everything is working good now, thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it really has nothing to do with Fancybox. Looking at your implementation, it looks like your hard-coded widths on the "detail" sections in each `<ul>` are pushing the edge of the Fancybox over. You should be able to eliminate most of the floats in `cartstyles.css`, and then you don't need to specify widths on those elements.

**EDIT:** I don't recommend doing this as a habit, but if the only complaint is the extra margin, try adding this rule to your stylesheet:

```
.fancybox-lock{
    margin-right:0 !important;
}
```

`!important` overrides the normal cascade, and would allow you to override the inline style applied by Fancybox. It would just be masking whatever the real issue is, though.

Comment: It happens when you click the "View Cart" button on the left side as well. I just replaced everything in the fancybox.html page (the page the buy a license button links) with a few words and it still moves the background, I'll leave the changes for you to check.

Comment: @NathanMurphree Are you able to reproduce this with a simpler site template? I suspect a conflict somewhere.

Comment: This is the only template I have. I'm sure it's something with this theme, I believe it might be the body background image: `body {background: #000000 url("images/back_1.png") repeat-y  top center; font: 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; color: #333; margin:0px; padding:0px;}`

Comment: @NathanMurphree When I used Firebug to inspect the popup, the paragraphs under each "option" were overflowing to the right. That is most likely what is causing the problem with your layout/background.

Comment: I don't think that's it, I just deleted all html in the popup page and wrote "this is a test" with no css and it still pushed the background image.

Comment: It's definitely Fancybox adding the margin, I ran across this post https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/347

Adding the locked: false fixes the margin issue but allows background scrolling, so still not exactly what I need.

`helpers : {
        overlay : {
            locked : false
        }
}`

Comment: `.fancybox-lock{
    margin-right:0!important;
}` 

That pushes the whole page over. I'll play around with some css and see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution to the same issue. After researching a few answers, a combination of my findings did the trick. 
Within the jquery.fancybox.css, make the following changes to the overlay helper section.

**BEFORE**

```
.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: auto;
}

.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-lock-test {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;
 z-index: 99999998010;
 background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**AFTER**

```
.fancybox-lock {

}

.fancybox-lock body {

}

.fancybox-lock-test {

}

.fancybox-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;

 display: none;
 z-index: 99999998010;
 background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {

}
```